# Can a pilot use glasses to meet the FAA required 20/20 vision?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilots, medical

When the FAA said that pilots require 20/20 vision, does that mean that you have to achieve 20/20 vision with glasses or without glasses?

Comment: For what level medical?

Comment: Any lvl 1/2 or 3

Answer (score 5):

It can be with correction. And note that for third class, distant vision only has to be correctable to 20/40. The near vision standard is 20/40 for all classes. See https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/standards/

As @Pondlife notes, the operative words here are,  "with or without correction."

Comment: So can I be a pilot if I have a power of 20/400 which can be corrected to 20/20 using glasses?

Comment: @JohnsonPaul I have around that range of vision in one eye (-5.75 correction) and had no issues getting a Class 2 medical in the UK. I realise yours is FAA centric but I find it hard to believe it'll differ much. Ironically mine corrects to 20/16 (6/5) which is better than average

Comment: I'm no AME, but I don't see any reason why not. There's no uncorrected vision requirement in what I linked, anyway.

Comment: You might want to quote the most relevant words from the AME guidance: "with or without correction".

Comment: And if you need corrective lenses, they become a restriction on your  medical certificate.  Mine states: Pilot must wear corrective lenses for distance vision while exercising the privileges of this certificate. Pilot must have in his possession corrective lenses for near vision when exercising the privileges of this certificate.

Comment: Of course, what @Gerry wrote above is very similar to what you'd probably get on a plain driver's license in a similar situation, too. I'm pretty sure this is EU-wide that there is no requirement on *uncorrected* vision there either, but if you need correction to meet the vision requirements, then a driver's license will also state that correction is required.

Comment: One thing to be vary of is laser correction. Do check the regulations carefully before deciding on an operation.